# variable scope for UILayout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var myLayout = $('#layoutContainer').layout({
        west__size:         450
    ,   east__size:         250
    });

    function toggleFullView() {
        myLayout.toggle('west');
    }

    $('#mapFooter').prepend('<a href="#" onClick="toggleFullView();" title="Toggle full view of map">Full View</a>');

}); // end document.ready
```

I keep getting an error 'toggleFullView is not defined' when I click the link created by the .prepend(). I've tried all sorts of messsing about. If I put the line from the toggleFullView function in the onClick i get the error - 'myLayout is not defined'.

what to do? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because toggleFullView exists in the scope of the `.ready()` callback, not the global scope of the script.

```
var MyModule = (function($) {
    // $ is now jQuery

    // This is only accessible from within MyModule
    var privateRyan = 'fubar';

    // Globally accessible with MyModule.toggleFullView
    this.toggleFullView = function() {
        myLayout.toggle('west');
    }

    $(document).ready( function() {
        // Do init stuff here
        var myLayout = $('#layoutContainer').layout({
                west__size:         450,
                east__size:         250});
        $('#mapFooter').prepend('<a href="#" onclick="MyModule.toggleFullView();" title="Toggle full view of map">Full View</a>');
    }); // end document.ready

})(jQuery); // () will execute this function immediately​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You could also create the link and then attach an event handler with [onclick](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and provide a callback.

Comment: thanks Aram and Andrew, you're both right. I declared myLayout outside the docready and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As Aram said, this is a scoping issue. Functions declared in the format "function funcName() {..." are considered local to the scope they are declared in.

To get round this do one of the following:

1) make the function global (not ideal - globals are evil)

2) use a namespace pattern, on which properties or methods that need to be globally accessible (not the same thing as global) can live, e.g.

```
var my_ns = {};
$(function() {
    my_ns.my_func = function() { alert('hello!'); };
    $('body').append("<a href='javascript:my_ns.my_func();'>click me</a>");
});
```

3) bind a click event rather than using the link's HREF - that way you store a reference to the func, even though it was declared in a now-inaccessible scope, e.g.

```
$(function() {
    var my_func = function() { alert('hello!'); };
    $('body').append($('<a />', {text: 'click me', href: '#'})).click(my_func);
});
```

Comment: Aram beat me to it - but it's broadly the same idea, i.e. making the function accessible via a global object - in his case, 'MyModule', in mine 'my_ns'.